# Can the tinylicious server be launched at a port other than 3000?

Tags: javascript, frontend, collaboration, fluid-framework

Can the tinylicious server be launched at a port other than 3000? I've tried something like "PORT=4100 tinylicious" and I can see the terminal log saying:

```
@federation/shell-app: [1] info: Listening on port 4100 {"label":"winston","timestamp":"2021-03-08T19:23:37.861Z"}
```

but later it fails within my code, indicating something went wrong with the service call:

```
main.js:15815 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'shapeClicked' of undefined
    at Layer.onClick [as zzClickFunc] (collabmap.component.js:45)
    at JS:24817
    at Array.<anonymous> (JS:8190)
    at window.<computed> (JS:1111)
    at Object.<anonymous> (JS:51778)
    at j (JS:51777)
```

and indeed, the Network tab reveals it's still posting via 3000:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/documents/tinylicious
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

I know tinylicious is not the full Fluid server and it's just for testing purposes, so it might have been hardwired to 3000, but maybe someone has an idea how to launch it on a different port.

Comment: I don't think it's configurable at the moment, but it should be. Can you open an issue?

Comment: done
https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/issues/5415

Answer (score 2):

Tinylicious server port is definitely configurable.

If you override their libraries, then you will be able to run your app using any port possible.

You must've noticed this function:

```
getTinyliciousContainer();
```

within its libraries - get-tinylicious-container and tinylicious-driver, you will see one of their files in the tinylicious-driver:
insecureTinyliciousUrlResolver.ts, in which every damn host:port is hardcoded to localhost:3000.

Therefore, just copy their code from their getTinyliciousContainer and tinylicious-driver, and make your own version of getTinyliciousContainer.  In the future, you need to copy these codes to configure for Routerlicious anyways, as Tinylicious is very lightweight, and is recommended just for testing purposes.
The file you need to modify in @fluidframework/tinylicious-driver is insecureTinyliciousUrlResolver.ts:

```
export class InsecureTinyliciousUrlResolver implements IUrlResolver {
public async resolve(request: IRequest): Promise<IResolvedUrl> {
    const url = request.url.replace(`http://${serviceHostName}:${servicePort}/`,"");
    const documentId = url.split("/")[0];
    const encodedDocId = encodeURIComponent(documentId);
    const documentRelativePath = url.slice(documentId.length);
    const serviceHostName = "YOUR-PREFERRED-HOST-NAME";
    const servicePort = "YOUR-PREFERRED-PORT";

    const documentUrl = `fluid://${serviceHostName}:${servicePort}/tinylicious/${encodedDocId}${documentRelativePath}`;
    const deltaStorageUrl = `http://${serviceHostName}:${servicePort}/deltas/tinylicious/${encodedDocId}`;
    const storageUrl = `http://${serviceHostName}:${servicePort}/repos/tinylicious`;

    const response: IFluidResolvedUrl = {
        endpoints: {
            deltaStorageUrl,
            ordererUrl: `http://${serviceHostName}:${servicePort}`,
            storageUrl,
        },
        tokens: { jwt: this.auth(documentId) },
        type: "fluid",
        url: documentUrl,
    };
    return response;
}

public async getAbsoluteUrl(resolvedUrl: IFluidResolvedUrl, relativeUrl: string): Promise<string> {
    const documentId = decodeURIComponent(resolvedUrl.url.replace(`fluid://${serviceHostName}:${servicePort}/tinylicious/`, ""));
    /*
     * The detached container flow will ultimately call getAbsoluteUrl() with the resolved.url produced by
     * resolve().  The container expects getAbsoluteUrl's return value to be a URL that can then be roundtripped
     * back through resolve() again, and get the same result again.  So we'll return a "URL" with the same format
     * described above.
     */
    return `${documentId}/${relativeUrl}`;
}

private auth(documentId: string) {
    const claims: ITokenClaims = {
        documentId,
        scopes: ["doc:read", "doc:write", "summary:write"],
        tenantId: "tinylicious",
        user: { id: uuid() },
        // @ts-ignore
        iat: Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000),
        exp: Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000) + 60 * 60, // 1 hour expiration
        ver: "1.0",
    };

    const utf8Key = { utf8: "12345" };
    return jsrsasign.jws.JWS.sign(null, JSON.stringify({ alg:"HS256", typ: "JWT" }), claims, utf8Key);
}
}

export const createTinyliciousCreateNewRequest =
    (documentId: string): IRequest=> (
        {
            url: documentId,
            headers:{
                createNew: true,
            },
        }
    );
```

Then, you just run this React app standalone instead of concurrently, and without the built-in Tinylicious server.

Go to their GitHub, clone their Tinylicious in the FluidFramework/server repo, and run it in whatever port you want.

And here you go, now you can run Tinylicious in any host, any port you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The Tinylicious  port is now configurable. More details in https://github.com/microsoft/FluidFramework/issues/5415

Comment: Thanks, Tyler. Got it.